# how to split 1GB JSON file into multiple JSON object file each

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON file of size 1GB which contains `n` number of twitter JSON Object tweets.Now I want to split large JSON file into single JSON Object each. But in large file the JSON chunks are space separated but not comma separated.

**INPUT :-**

```
{
"created_at": "Tue Aug 06 06:01:00 +0000 2013",
"id": 364627145785487360,
"id_str": "364627145785487360",
"text": "Soo sad right now..",
"filter_level": "medium",
"lang": "en"
}
{
"created_at": "Tue Aug 06 06:01:00 +0000 2013",
"id": 364627145785487360,
"id_str": "364627145785487361",
"text": "الضمير صوت هادىء يخبرك بأن احدا ينظر اليك",
"lang": "en"
}
```

Now my OUTPUT has to be as shown below

**OUTPUT: Test1.json**

```
{
"created_at": "Tue Aug 06 06:01:00 +0000 2013",
"id": 364627145785487360,
"id_str": "364627145785487360",
"text": "Soo sad right now..",
"filter_level": "medium",
"lang": "en"
}
```

**Test2.json**

```
{
"created_at": "Tue Aug 06 06:01:00 +0000 2013",
"id": 364627145785487360,
"id_str": "364627145785487361",
"text": "الضمير صوت هادىء يخبرك بأن احدا ينظر اليك",
"lang": "en"
}
```

Can anyone help me out to get the above output JSON files i.e, `Test1.json`, `Test2.json`

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Which part of your code is not working?

Comment: the input is not valid JSON.

Comment: Yes, that is not valid JSON but how can I make it as valid JSON . My input file is not valid JSON. But as individual chunks i.e., Test1.json and Test2.json they are valid JSON chunks@P.J.Meisch

Answer (score 0):

given number of lines (7000 in this case):

command : **jq -c -M '.data[]' | split -l 7000**